# i'd like to insert a $ sign before numerical value in a sql database how could i do it?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

shouid i use **concate** operator or **forma**t?

Comment: Numbers don't store string values.  Add the currency when you query the table.

Comment: Please share more details. What's your exact problem? What have you tried to resolve it?

Comment: Distinguish storing/processing/retrieving and displaying. The last task is client one, not database server one - instruct the client to add `$` to the value of this column (in grid properties).

Answer (score 0):

No. If you want to provide a reliable, expandable schema then store the value as valueand the currency as code in your data table.
Build an ISO 4217 table for the currencies and its symbols.

Then build a view that joins your value and ISO 4217 tables that transforms your value to a string for output formatting.

Comment: The next question from your users will then be: Why is it impossible to sum up the "values" (that are strings)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store values with dollar sign, the valid-relational-way of doing that will be to add a table with currencies (columns: id, name, sign) and put dollar in that table. In the table with prices you can refer to that table to link numbers with currencies.

If you want to query data like that use `select concat('$', number) from table;`